# JSP pass parameter to servlet according to button clicked

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, parameters

I have the following JSP which contains a form. The user should be able to update and delete, so I have two buttons for these options:

```
<form method="GET" action ="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/CurrencyController">
        Currency code: <input type="text" name="currencyCode" id="currencyCode" value="${currency.currencyCode}" /> 
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" >
        <input type="submit" value="Delete"/>
    </form>
```

In my servlet `CurrencyController` I retrieve the `action`:

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("update")){
        ...
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete")){
        ...
```

So how can I pass the value for `action` in my form? It should be `update` if the first button is clicked and `delete` if the second button is clicked

Answer (score 1):

Add action parameter using new input:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="" />
```

Add onClick attribure to each submit button that will change its value. for example:

```
 onClick="document.getElementId('action').value=this.value;return true;"
```

Comment: I have now: `<input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="" /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Update" onClick="document.getElementId('action').value=update" /> 
        <input type="button" value="Delete" onClick="document.getElementId('action').value=delete"/>` But parameter `action` is empty string in servlet :/